# Regex ignore the line with underscore

Tags: regex, vb.net

`Regex.Match(line, "^\[(\w+)[^_]]")`

When the string contains underscore, I would like no match.

Example:

Line 1: [String] returns String

Line 2: [String_Ab] returns String_AB.

I would like to return line 1 match String removing the brackets. Skip Line 2 because the string contains underscore. Right now `"^\[(\w+)[^_]]")`, returns String and String_AB.

Comment: How about `If line.IndexOf("_"c) = -1 Then` process line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a pattern to get a match only between square brackets without matching an underscore, you might use:

```
(?<=\[)[^][_]*(?=])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\[)` Assert `[` to the left
- `[^][_]*` Match optional chars other than `[` `]` and `_`
- `(?=]) Assert` ]` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h0iX6Q/1)

Or using a capture group

```
\[([^][_]*)]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/moIJhA/1)